# How to address a Chrome tab that is inside a saved tab group?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I used to be able to switch between tabs (current tab and previous tab) by using the following code inside my Chrome extension:

```
function switchTabs() {
    let prevTab = tabHistory[currentTabId].prev;
    if (prevTab.id) { // Check if is dummy start.
        chrome.tabs.update(prevTab.id, {active: true});
}}
```

This does no longer work, however, if the previous or current tab is part of a saved tab group. The below screenshots shows what I am referring to with a saved tab group.

[image]

What exactly changed with the new saved tab groups that makes addressing the tab inside a saved tab group no longer possible with the above code?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: It's probably the same bug: https://crbug.com/323982812

Comment: I am going to follow this bug, thanks!